# Changing the value of a macro at run time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010, using C++ code. What I'm trying to do is change the value of a preprocessor directive during run time, not sure if it's possible but I've tried this..

somefile.h

```
static int mValue = 0;
#define POO = mValue;
...

#if POO 0
//define class methods
#else
//define class methods differently
}
```

main.cpp

```
main()
{

//Code calls constructor and methods allowed when POO is 0

//Code increments mValue

//Code calls constructor and methods allowed when POO is 1


}
```

How can POO be changed so that class objects use a different implementation of other methods? Or if it's not possible, what's another approach to this?

Comment: You cannot change preprocessor directives at runtime. Using a base class with different derived classes may work, depending on your problem (which is hard to tell from what you've shown us).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the nature of "preprocessor" directive.  These only exist before compiler processing.  The compiler eliminates (replaces/processes) macro definitions during the compile step.  They don't exist at runtime to change.  It's actually a mini-language unto itself that only compiles into c/c++ code, which is then processed by the compiler.

It sounds like you want your class to be two different things based on some sort of runtime input.  This may indicate a design problem.  You might consider defining two different classes (possibly with a common trivial base class).